# HTML5 button not hiding

Tags: html

I am using HTML5. I like to hide a button
I am using the following:

```
     $('#butt1').hide();

     <button id="butt1">Button1</button>
```

Any idea why it may not be working in HTML5

Comment: I'm not getting, what this issue has to do with HTML5. Do you use semantic tags? Do you use any HTML5 modules? `<button>` is probably as old as html itself, so this is in no way related to you problem.

Comment: Either tag with `jquery` or `javascript` this problem has nothing to do with what Standard you're using

Comment: [Added an edit into the queue]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

put it between:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

      //....My blah di blah  

        $('#butt1').hide(); 

      //....My other stuff 

});
```

By the way, your issue has nothing to do with Html 5.

Answer (score 0):

1. https://stackoverflow.com/a/10357651/139010, or
2. Move the `<script>` tags to be **after** the `<button>` tag in the markup.

Answer (score 0):

Your jQuery needs to be in script tags.